# Identifying SS42316-01 02632R 642W

Tags: components, identification

I salvaged this from an old Phillips CRT.

It mentions: SS42316-01 02632R 642W

What is this component?

It has 12 pins, and does not have broken pins despite the gaps.

[[image]
[[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is a transformer, probably running at some high (for power circuits) frequency

This is a transformer of the E-I core type, with what appears to be a "belly band" of copper for EMI control as well.  Something like this would be used in a switching power supply of some sort, which is somewhat curious considering most TVs actually derived their supply voltages from windings on the flyback transformer instead of having a separate power supply save for getting the horizontal stages up and running.

It's not that likely to be useful to you as it was custom wound for its application most likely, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... too bad I cannot use it, it's quite big, but maybe I keep it in a box with 'first salvage project' items as 'trophy' :-)

Answer (score 2):

Appears on page 26 of the L04E AA Chassis Service Manual as component number 5512 with its variants listed on page 27.
([Service Manual Link 1](http://mavelec11.schemas.free.fr/Philips/L04E_AA_EN.pdf) or [Service Manual Link 2](http://diagramas.diagramasde.com/televisores/Philips%20chassis%20l04ha_aa_312278514810_en.pdf))

A search for 2422-531-02634 helps find [a potential revendor](http://www.recampro.com/view/catalogo/ls_catalogo.php?q=2422-531-02634&busquedaen=pc_o_ce&lang=es&busqueda=1) regarding a potential spare part source with part number SS42315-01 (not SS42316-01) possibly more complete than your part as the service manual does not mention spare parts for the other variants.

[image: Component schematic image from service manual]

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. L04E does not say anything to me (but I couldn't see the model of the TV anymore). I doubt I ever will use this part. Thanks for the detailed search.